# Pandas qcut returns two different results with the same data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created two dummy data with the same format then using pd qcut and got different results. Please tell me how to make the output correct (like data 1)?

Data 1:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(list(np.zeros(10)) + list (np.ones(2)), columns=['X'])
df1=df[['X']].assign(var_bin=lambda x: pd.qcut(x['X'], q=20, duplicates='drop'))
df1['var_bin'].unique()
```

output
`[(-0.001, 0.35], (0.9, 1.0]] Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 0.35] < (0.9, 1.0]]`

Data 2:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(list(np.zeros(1000)) + list (np.ones(200)), columns=['X'])
df1=df[['X']].assign(var_bin=lambda x: pd.qcut(x['X'], q=20, duplicates='drop'))
df1['var_bin'].unique()
```

output

`[(-0.001, 1.0]] Categories (1, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 1.0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the number of quantiles when you upscale you dummy dataset:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(np.zeros(1000)) + list (np.ones(200)), columns=['X'])
df1=df[['X']].assign(var_bin=lambda x: pd.qcut(x['X'], q=2000, duplicates='drop'))
df1['var_bin'].unique()
```

which gives:

```
[(-0.001, 0.366], (0.966, 1.0]]
Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 0.366] < (0.966, 1.0]]
```